# Plotting to seperate pdf files based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    NDVI   Value   Allotment   Date
0      0  0.208430  Arnstson  19840517
1      0  0.211430  Arnstson  19840517
2      0  0.214430  Arnstson  19840517
3      2  0.217430  Arnstson  19840517
4      4  0.220430  Arnstson  19840517
5      1  0.223430  Arnstson  19840517
6      6  0.226430  Arnstson  19840517
7      1  0.229430  Arnstson  19840517
8     11  0.232430  Arnstson  19840517
9     13  0.235430  Arnstson  19840517
10    17  0.238430  Arnstson  19840517
11     9  0.241430  Arnstson  19840517
12     9  0.244430  Arnstson  19840517
13     7  0.247430  Arnstson  19840517
14    22  0.250430  Woodlot   19840517
15    17  0.253430  Woodlot   19840517
16    14  0.256430  Woodlot   19840517
17     5  0.259430  Woodlot   19840517
18    14  0.262430  Woodlot   19840517
19    19  0.265430  Woodlot   19840517
20    10  0.268430  Woodlot   19840517
21    11  0.271430  Arnstson  19840518
22    10  0.274430  Arnstson  19840518
23     9  0.277430  Arnstson  19840518
24     9  0.280430  Arnstson  19840518
25     5  0.283430  Woodlot   19840518
26     7  0.286430  Woodlot   19840518
27     1  0.289430  Woodlot   19840518
28    11  0.292430  Woodlot   19840518
29     6  0.295430  Woodlot   19840518
```

and I want to create plots based on the `Allotment` that are sent to different pdf files.  So I want all plots which contain unique `Allotment` names sent to one file which plot `NDVI` vs. `Value` for each respective `Date`.  I can do this easily for an individual `Allotment` with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

group=df.groupby(['Allotment'])
Arnstson=group.get_group('Arnstson')

with PdfPages(r'C:\delete.pdf') as pdf:
    for i, group in Arnstson.groupby(['Allotment', 'Date']):
        plot=group.plot(x='Value', y='NDVI', title=str(i)).get_figure()
        pdf.savefig(plot)  
        plt.close(plot)
```

but I have 53 unique names in `Allotment` and would prefer not to have to select all of them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy is to open all of the PDF files, write to the appropriate ones, and then close them.  Here I use a dictionary to track the file handles where `Allotment` is the key.  I write them all then close all file handles in a separate step.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pdf_files = {}
for group_name, group in df.groupby(['Allotment', 'Date']):
    allotment, date = group_name
    if allotment not in pdf_files:
        pdf_files[allotment] = PdfPages('C:\\' + allotment + '.pdf') 
    plot=group.plot(x='Value', y='NDVI', title=str(group_name)).get_figure()
    pdf_files[allotment].savefig(plot)
    plt.close(plot)

for key in pdf_files:
    pdf_files[key].close()
```

An alternative would be to use a nested group by, where the outer groupby used `Allotment` and the inner (used on the group from the outer) used `Date`.  This would allow the file to be open and closed one at a time, and would be better if there were potentially lots of `Allotment`s.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pdf_files = {}
for allotment, outer_group  in df.groupby(['Allotment']):
    with PdfPages('C:\\' + allotment '.pdf') as pdf:
        for date, inner_group in outer_group.groupby(['Date']):
            plot=group.plot(x='Value', y='NDVI', title=str(allotment, date)).get_figure()
            pdf.savefig(plot)
            plt.close(plot)
```

This version is a little shorter, although it does involve nested loops.  I prefer the second as it seem a bit clearer as well.